# SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location error with Selenium and Firefox

Tags: selenium, firefox, geckodriver, webdriver-manager, webdrivermanager-python

I don't know why but yeasterday and the day before it worked but today no.
I changed nothing and the PATH is always at the same place.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
import pandas as pd
import re
import time



driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
driver.get(("https://cordis.europa.eu/search/fr?q=contenttype%3D%27project%27%20AND%20programme%2Fcode%3D%27H2020%27&p=1&num=10&srt=/project/contentUpdateDate:decreasing"))
```

I have that big error message :

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
SessionNotCreatedException                Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\JOHAN~1.ROC\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_6336/1824966143.py in <module>
----> 1 driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
      2 driver.get(("https://cordis.europa.eu/search/fr?q=contenttype%3D%27project%27%20AND%20programme%2Fcode%3D%27H2020%27&p=1&num=10&srt=/project/contentUpdateDate:decreasing"))
      3 
      4 
      5 #link = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/app-root/ng-component/main/div/div/section[2]/section[2]/app-card-search[1]/div/div[2]/a")

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py in __init__(self, firefox_profile, firefox_binary, timeout, capabilities, proxy, executable_path, options, service_log_path, firefox_options, service_args, desired_capabilities, log_path, keep_alive)
    168             executor = FirefoxRemoteConnection(
    169                 remote_server_addr=self.service.service_url)
--> 170             RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
    171                 self,
    172                 command_executor=executor,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in __init__(self, command_executor, desired_capabilities, browser_profile, proxy, keep_alive, file_detector, options)
    155             warnings.warn("Please use FirefoxOptions to set browser profile",
    156                           DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
--> 157         self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
    158         self._switch_to = SwitchTo(self)
    159         self._mobile = Mobile(self)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in start_session(self, capabilities, browser_profile)
    250         parameters = {"capabilities": w3c_caps,
    251                       "desiredCapabilities": capabilities}
--> 252         response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
    253         if 'sessionId' not in response:
    254             response = response['value']

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line
```

If you have an idea of why it why it does not work and why doesn't it work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the issue is with `get()`. While invoking *`get()`* you need to pass the *url_string* as the argument. So instead of `get(("url_string"))` it should have been `get("url_string")`.

Effectively, your line of code would be:

```
driver.get("https://cordis.europa.eu/search/fr?q=contenttype%3D%27project%27%20AND%20programme%2Fcode%3D%27H2020%27&p=1&num=10&srt=/project/contentUpdateDate:decreasing")
```

Comment: Thanks but no it does not change the result ^^: 
SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line

Comment: Selenium version?

Comment: Version 3.141.0. I used it on Anaconda.

Comment: Any good reason to use `from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service` ?

Comment: No sorry i'm realy new with selenium and i have so many probleme and i copy past the answer of some pages. I tried to find the best and easier way to scrap with selenium but when i solved sommes probleme 2 days latter that change.